# cannot read function outside axios

Tags: javascript, axios

I have a isUserLogged() function that is called when a certain condition is met inside axios, however it returns an error saying **Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError**. Is there a way on how to call the function outside? Thank you.

This is my code.

```
axios.post('/webservices/getaccountinfo.ashx?o=all')
  .then(function (response) {
   /*Selector*/ 
    var pPanel = document.querySelector('.product-panel');
    var panelHead = document.querySelector("#pLshow div:nth-child(2)");      
    var userLogged = false;

if(response.data.Email !== null){
     console.log(response.data.Email);
      userLogged = true;
    isUserLogged(response.data.FirstName, response.data.LastName, response.data.Email);

   }

  }).catch(function (error) {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  });

function isUserlogged(fname, lname, email){
     console.log('pass function outside');
}
```

Note: I am not using reactJS.

Comment: it's a horrendous solution but you can try with eval ()

Comment: @GianfrancescoAurecchia thanks for your reply, why do you say its horrendous?

Comment: eval() is not a solution but a stratagem to bypass the problem, in all cases it would work

Comment: in your cases is eval("isUserLogged('"+response.data.FirstName+"','"+ response.data.LastName+"', '"+response.data.Email+"')");

Comment: eval() did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo. The function in the global scope is defined as isUser**l**ogged, but you are calling isUser**L**ogged

Comment: wow, sometimes i am a freakin idiot. lol. thank you for noticing it,

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute a custom callback, I would recommend making use of a wrapper function. Something like

```
function isUserlogged(response){
    var pPanel = document.querySelector('.product-panel');
    var panelHead = document.querySelector("#pLshow div:nth-child(2)");      
    var userLogged = false;

if(response.data.Email !== null){
     console.log(response.data.Email);
      userLogged = true;
    isUserLogged(response.data.FirstName, response.data.LastName, response.data.Email);
   }
console.log('pass function outside');
}

function post(resource, url){
    return axios.post(url, resource)
}

post(dataMock,'/webservices/getaccountinfo.ashx?o=all')
.then(isUserLogged))
.catch(function (error) {
    //your catch logic
});
```

Comment: may I know the good parts of this, if I used this one? thank you for your suggestion, appreciate it.

Comment: Generally while working on an app, you would end up making a lot of server requests. With each request requires some configuration, like `tokens`, `appkey`. You would't want to configure these requests each time. So a better way is to put them all wrapped inside a config function which sets the initial configurations for all your calls, in return you end up handleling all your configuration at one place. which is helpful when it comes to debugging and code updates.